# Camel netty4-http client handling of http 100-Continue

Tags: apache-camel, netty

We are using netty4-http as a client and have a problem when the server side answers with a http 100-Continue.
I expected the client to handle that internally and continue the call but it's actually returning http 100.

The test org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpClientExpectContinueTest in the Camel code seems to test exactly that situation but it's ignored with the comment "TODO Fix it, need to send the response back". So I guess it has been a plan to implement it.

I'm new too Netty I wondering if it's possible to handle that in the Netty pipeline by overriding the ClientInitializerFactory (I found out it's the HttpObjectAggregator that returns 100)?
So any help how do achieve that in the Netty pipeline or any tips how to achieve that in some other way is welcome.

Comment: Why not try to help implement this in camel-netty4-http? And then provide a PR with the fix. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket about it. And btw have you tried with latest Camel version as it may be fixed/working there.

Comment: If I find a good solution I will try to create a PR. Right now I don't  know how to do it, or if it's the best and prefered way to do it with the Netty channel handlers in the pipeline or in some other way in Camel. So any tips is welcome.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: We are using 2.24.0. I had a look in the Camel master branch but couldn't see any fixes for this.

Comment: Okay yeah it sounds like a good thing to get implemented OOTB, would you create a JIRA ticket about this in the issue tracker: https://camel.apache.org/community/support/

Comment: Sorry for late response, it has been really busy weeks. I created issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues/CAMEL-14069 and provided our solution for it. Is there any information available how to participate in the Camel development?